# Font is hard to read

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, design

I don't know how else to express this. The font in "wall of text"-style questions is much harder to read than on SO. On SO, the font on posts is so much cleaner. Also, why is *italics* bold?

The font is also harder to read in other places on the site. I think you should change it to something easier on the eye.

[Screenshot of a question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iodxY.png)

Comment: the font is the same on all the sites....  Regardless this is an engine question more meant for the likes of meta.so as ALL the beta sites have the same style regardless

Comment: @TylerShads I hadn't realised all beta sites use the same font (I haven't used any other beta sites). Feel free to close this, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your browser, since movies.se uses the same font as *StackOverflow*, likewise is italics *not* bold (at least on my machine and the others I've used to view SE sites in the past).

Comment: @ChristianRau Stack Overflow questions are set to `font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;`. Movies is set to `font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;`. Probably you're seeing the fonts "the same" because you don't have Helvetica installed.

Comment: @ChristianRau I've updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: That looks squished as hell and doesn't look like Helvecta at all.  Are you sure you don't have the site zoomed on any level in your browser?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I can see both Helvetica Neue(on OSX) and Arial (on Windows) just fine. What OS are you using? If you're on PC do you have an un-authentic Helvetica font installed?

Comment: @Jin It seems a copy of Helvetica a client had given me is... less than reputable. Sorry for the confusion! Uninstalled :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's just you... Maybe you haven't the proper font installed? Or some option is having problems with the CSS?

This is how I see it:

> [image]

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my comment above, Helvetica takes preference over Arial in Movies' stylesheet. The reason we are seeing it differently is because *you* don't have the proper font installed.. so you're seeing the next best option: Arial. IMO, Helvetica needs to be removed from the stylesheet and Arial kept.

Comment: @DannyBeckett But it's not *me* who's having the problem. How do you reconcile that with the fact that I see it properly?

Comment: I just tried to compare them and that font in your screenshot doesn't look like any of the styles for Helvetica or Helvetica Neue. Are you sure it's not some other font bothering?

Comment: @DannyBeckett the font in your screenshot is totally not properly rendered Helvetica